# .gitignore is not ignoring directories

Tags: git, version-control, github, gitignore

**What I did:**

I think there were some weird configurations from the github gui that caused this issue and prevented me from being able to easily use git from command line or even git-bash.

I ended up just uninstalling github and git then reinstalling just git for windows. I now have everything running off the command line(except ssh which I run from git-bash). Much easier and more reliable that the github gui.

Thanks to mu 無 for taking the time to try to figure this out. I didn't end up using his answer, but if I hadn't needed to do a reinstall of git it would have been what I needed to do.

---

I am using the github gui on my local machine. I just noticed that a commit I was about to make was going to update all of my recently update node modules. I set up my .gitignore to ignore the entire `node_modules/` directory.

I'm not sure what to do about this. All the file types I included in .gitignore were ignored. It's just the directories that it seems to ignore.

Here is my .gitignore file:

```
#################
## Sublime Text
#################

*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace

#################
## Images
#################

*.jpg
*.jpeg
*.png
*.gif
*.psd
*.ai

#################
## Windows detritus
#################

# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Mac crap
.DS_Store

#################
## Directories
#################

dev/
cms/core/config/
node_modules/
```

Comment: what is the output of `git status`? Add that to the question...

Comment: I don't know anything about that

Comment: Go to your terminal, and run `git status` in the repository. Whatever is the output, put them here.

Comment: I am on a windows machine. So terminal git commands don't work. `'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Can you check if any file within the node_modules folder is already tracked? You will need to run `git log node_modules` in it bash, or check it on github.

Comment: Yes, the node_modules directory is already committed from the originial commit. But the .gitignore file was in place at the time and was set to ignore the `node_modules/` directory

Comment: I tried ignoring a newly created directory containing a .txt file and it worked fine.

Comment: Check edits to my answer, you need to untrack the directory. Most probably it was being tracked even before you added the `.gitignore` entry, hence it didn't get ignored in the first place.

Comment: Look this: [making git forget about a file that was tracked but is now in gitignore | StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore/1274447#1274447)

Comment: @HalCarleton I'd recommend Git Bash. You can also use it as terminal in some IDEs (VSCode for sure). You can then use the early-on suggestions.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

Since the `node_modules` directory is already tracked as part of the repository, the `.gitignore` rule will not apply to it.

You need to untrack the directory from git using

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
git commit -m "removing node_modules"
```

You can run the above 2 in `git-bash`.

After this, the `.gitignore` rule will ignore the directory away.

Note that this will remove the directory `node_modules` from your other repos once you pull the changes in. Only the original repo where you made that commit will still have the `node_modules` folder there.

Comment: That is not a typo. The directory created by node is `node_modules/`

Comment: the ignore rule is `node_modules`, and in your question, at the beginning it is `node_module`.

Comment: How do I untrack without command line? Or how do I access git in command line on a windows machine and no bash?

Comment: go to `git-bash`. Git for windows comes with its own `git-bash`. How do you otherwise commit from windows?

Comment: I commit with the github gui. That's all I've ever used in windows. On linux I can just access git from the command line.

Comment: Then do it on linux :). Note however this will remove the directory `node_modules` from your other repos once you pull the changes in

Comment: I'm working on this repo on a windows machine where I need the directory. I found git-bash, but don't have access to this repo

Comment: I don't think github gui allows for commands like `git rm` to be run. Btw what do you mean by you don't have access? you can `cd` to the repository path, and then run the commands afaik.

Comment: I can't cd to the path. I have a directory with all my working repos in it. It will only `ls` one of the repos and it is not the one I'm trying to fix

Comment: I used `ls` inside the containing directory and it only listed one sub-directory when there is actually several. But I'll play around with it. Or maybe just SSH into the live server that this deploys to and do it there.

Comment: Cool then. Do remember that it will remove the `node_modules` from all other cones/forks, except the one on which you run this command.

Comment: `git rm -r --cached node_modules` remove it. but next time when i use `git add .` it add the folder again. What the hack is this?

Comment: @Max Did you add it to the `.gitignore`?

Comment: Yes i have, it works for other folder. i fix it by adding directry name in .git\info\exclude file

Comment: I had the same issue with my `node_modules` not been ignored. I think it is because I had generated the folder before adding my `.gitignore` file. What I did to fix it without using the command above is to delete the `node_modules` folder and regenerate it. Some how, when it meets the `.gitignore` file already present, the ignore rule will apply.

Comment: Using the command `git rm -r --cached node_modules` had not effect, it worked after I forced the command with -f.

Answer (score 34):

Similar to Zach, I also used `echo "node_modules/" >> .gitignore`.

The problem was it had created the file with encoding `UCS-2 LE BOM`. Using [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) I changed the encoding to UTF-8 and voila - node_modules is now ignored.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was really frustrating me.

Comment: This answer should have much more up votes as the problem and solution are really surprising. Thank you!

Comment: I did exactly this, fml.
Just deleted and re-created using VS Studio. Thanks @Scotty.NET

Answer (score 21):

If the files are already tracked the `.gitignore` file will not override this. You will need to use `git rm --cached <files>`

See the full details on `git rm` at
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html 
I ran into this once or twice myself early on with git and it was not quite what I expected either.

Comment: This is more comprehensive answer to the title in question if we ignore the typo problems in the OP's question. Useful for people arriving w/ search.

Answer (score 4):

If you work with node projects, I like this `.gitignore`:

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
node_modules

# testing
coverage

# production
build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env
npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. Somehow when I generated the file (using echo "node_modules" > .gitignore) it had inserted a garbage character at the beginning of the file (I blame powershell).

So, if you run into this problem try deleting your .gitignore and starting over.

Comment: Seems to be a powershell issue, since same thing happened here.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me and I don't know why

Eventually what I did was:

1. Duplicated to project folder in order to don't work with the main one
2. Then I removed .git & .gitignore file (CMD+SHIFT+DOT  shows hidden files)
3. Added .gitignore file with `touch .gitignore` at root and added `node_modules`
4. Initialized git again with `git init`
5. Added remote again with `git remote add origin your_repo`
6. `git add .`
7. `git commit -m 'added ignore file'`
8. `git push -u origin master`

And continue working with this new directory.
Please note that it was a solution for me because it was my first commit.

Answer (score 0):

Well what works for me was add "node_modules" to .gitignore

```
backend\node_modules
frontend\your_proyect\node_modules
node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the initial git configuration from your folder by
*`rm -rf .git`*. Use the created .gitignore file and add all the file you want to add. Then reinitialize the git configuration in your folder with *`git init`*.
This will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

try this command, it will resolve your issue:

```
git config core.ignorecase true
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't seen this posted anywhere, as perhaps it should be obvious, until I forgot, but adding a comment to the end of a gitignore line is NOT actually a comment! Comments on their own line!

```
# .gitignore (this is a comment)
my_bad_dir/ # This is not a comment, and my_bad_dir/ won't be ignored
```

```
~$ man gitignore | grep comment
       •   A line starting with # serves as a comment.
```