# The .gitignore file is Ignored

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with two projects in VS 2015, and I want to remove the obj and bin directories from version control.

From the beginning, my `.gitignore` has the following:

```
[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
*.obj
*.exe
```

When I follow the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924633/gitignore-is-not-ignoring-directories) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository/1139797#1139797), the files are removed.

But the next time I compile, they are added to the project again.
What am I doing wrong, and how can I get rid of those directories permanently?

**Edit**

To be clear, the question relates to the git interface offered within VS2015.

Answer (score 1):

> ...obj and bin directories from

you have to specify it as folders (starting with the `/`)

```
**/[Bb]in/
**/[Oo]bj/
```

I have created a `bin` folder and then added it to the .`gitignore` as showed above. As you can see the changes are in the `.gitconfig` in which i added the changes but `bin` folder is not in the status anymore.

Here are the results:
[image]

Comment: That is not correct, the syntax OP is using works fine. `**` annotation just makes git ignore the folders in any depth, not just the same folder where the .gitignore file is.

Comment: Where do you see ** in the OP? there is only *.obj in the question

Comment: I did not say that there is ** in the original post.

Comment: This is incorrect. The trailing / is used to identify a folder. The leading / just makes .gitignore look in the root folder for the given folder name, thush adding **/ is the same as not using anything leading at all.

Answer (score 0):

After committing on the command line, the problem seems to have gone away. I'm not sure that this is the answer. I am fairly sure that Visual Studio does all sorts of things behind the scenes with git. Is there any documentation of how the VS front-end for git works?

Comment: you never said in the question that you're not using the command line. This is relevant information to be added to the question itself.