# Git is committing node_modules despite being ignored

Tags: node.js, git, github

One of the dependencies in my project uses chromium (which is over 100mb) and makes github throw an error when trying to push it.

To solve this, I made sure to ignore my node_modules folder.

However I still get the error when I try to push.

Here is my .gitignore file:

```
.env
node_modules
node_modules/*
```

Here's the output of `git ls-tree -r master --name-only`:

```
.DS_Store
.gitignore
README.md
app.js
package-lock.json
package.json
public/index.html
public/sign-in-with-twitter.png
public/styles.css
server.js
utils/.DS_Store
utils/database.js
utils/encryption.js
utils/gradients.js
utils/increments.js
utils/twitter.js
```

And here's the full error when trying to push:

```
remote: D, [2020-09-16T12:48:02.974268 #49478] DEBUG -- : FAILBOT EXCEPTION: action=processing exception=NoMethodError original_type: GitHub::PreReceiveBlob::PushRejected data={"release"=>"6507d92df20b3ea50e34effb905bb46f3d94cc3d", "current_ref"=>"train-b4ab8774", "app"=>"github-user", "ruby"=>"ruby 2.7.1p92 (2020-07-11 revision 4ec8c70524) [x86_64-linux]", "server"=>"github-dfs-08e6617.va3-iad.github.net", "deployed_to"=>"production", "kube_namespace"=>"unknown", "pusher"=>"gb221", "proto"=>"ssh", "path"=>"/data/repositories/7/nw/79/2e/61/297891227/295655929.git", "from"=>"hooks/pre-receive.rb.rb [gb221/gradient-twitter.git]", "audit_msg"=>"{ \"above_lock_quota\":false, \"above_warn_quota\":false, \"babeld\":\"61941ce7\", \"babeld_proto\":\"ssh\", \"check_lfs_integrity\":false, \"cmdline\":\"/usr/lib/git-core/git receive-pack .\", \"committer_date\":\"1600285604 -0700\", \"disable_hooks\":true, \"features\":\" report-status side-band-64k agent=git/2.22.0\", \"frontend\":\"unicorn-gitauth-api-654b85c97f-s5c4m\", \"frontend_pid\":133, \"frontend_ppid\":6, \"git_dir\":\"/data/repositories/7/nw/79/2e/61/297891227/295655929.git\", \"git_dir_safe\":\"/data/repositories/7/nw/79/2e/61/297891227/295655929.git\", \"gitauth_version\":\"6507d92d\", \"hostname\":\"github-dfs-08e6617.va3-iad.github.net\", \"pgroup\":\"64872\", \"pid\":64872, \"ppid\":64848, \"program\":\"receive-pack\", \"proxy_pre_fetch_and_detect_have_present\":false, \"pubkey_creator_id\":18144602, \"pubkey_creator_login\":\"gb221\", \"pubkey_fingerprint\":\"75:cb:2d:06:a1:8a:34:db:b7:cf:27:8d:2d:f8:15:90\", \"pubkey_id\":46204985, \"pubkey_verifier_id\":18144602, \"pubkey_verifier_login\":\"gb221\", \"quotas_enabled\":true, \"real_ip\":\"86.146.63.195\", \"received_objects\":2909, \"remote_addr\":\"10.56.111.46\", \"remote_port\":\"54238\", \"repo_config\":\"{\\\"allow_auto_deleting_branches\\\":\\\"false\\\",\\\"dependency_vulnerability_alerts.disabled\\\":\\\"true\\\",\\\"repository_dependency_updates.vulnerabilities.disabled\\\":\\\"true\\\",\\\"tiered_reporting\\\":\\\"false\\\"}\", \"repo_id\":295655929, \"repo_name\":\"gb221/gradient-twitter\", \"repo_public\":false, \"request_id\":\"fccb4e4a60b223744cc60e177b626e75\", \"status\":\"pre_receive_hook\", \"use_http_postrx\":true, \"user_id\":18144602, \"user_login\":\"gb221\", \"user_operator_mode\":false }", "env"=>"production", "error_code"=>"45a2d52ef1b728ec2c1124abf968e3d6", "exception_detail"=>[{"type"=>"GitHub::PreReceiveBlob::PushRejected", "value"=>"GitHub::PreReceiveBlob::PushRejected", "stacktrace"=>[]}], "created_at"=>"2020-09-16T19:48:02.973358Z", "refs"=>"refs/heads/master: 0dbd850362f939fe02d2e656912a42fdebb32eff", "files"=>"node_modules/svg-to-img/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-536395/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/Versions/66.0.3347.0/Chromium Framework.framework/Versions/A/Chromium Framework: 125274684 bytes", "repo_id"=>295655929, "rollup"=>"2a7bc1e29623942867c40e965f833e13"}
remote: D, [2020-09-16T12:48:02.974312 #49478] DEBUG -- : GitHub::PreReceiveBlob::PushRejected
remote: D, [2020-09-16T12:48:02.975337 #49478] DEBUG -- : undefined method `hour' for 1:Integer
remote: D, [2020-09-16T12:48:02.975391 #49478] DEBUG -- : /data/github/releases/20200916185747-6507d92df20b3ea50e34effb905bb46f3d94cc3d/lib/github/config/failbot.rb:86:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote: /data/github/releases/20200916185747-6507d92df20b3ea50e34effb905bb46f3d94cc3d/vendor/gems/2.7.1/ruby/2.7.0/gems/failbot-2.5.5/lib/failbot.rb:345:in `report!'
remote: /data/github/releases/20200916185747-6507d92df20b3ea50e34effb905bb46f3d94cc3d/vendor/gems/2.7.1/ruby/2.7.0/gems/failbot-2.5.5/lib/failbot.rb:322:in `report'
remote: /data/github/releases/20200916185747-6507d92df20b3ea50e34effb905bb46f3d94cc3d/lib/github/githooks/pre_receive_blob.rb:75:in `check'
remote: /data/github/releases/20200916185747-6507d92df20b3ea50e34effb905bb46f3d94cc3d/lib/github/githooks/push_context.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in check'
remote: /data/github/releases/20200916185747-6507d92df20b3ea50e34effb905bb46f3d94cc3d/vendor/gems/2.7.1/ruby/2.7.0/gems/dogstatsd-ruby-4.1.0/lib/datadog/statsd.rb:356:in `time'
remote: /data/github/releases/20200916185747-6507d92df20b3ea50e34effb905bb46f3d94cc3d/lib/github/githooks/push_context.rb:39:in `block in check'
remote: /data/github/releases/20200916185747-6507d92df20b3ea50e34effb905bb46f3d94cc3d/lib/github/githooks/push_context.rb:34:in `each'
remote: /data/github/releases/20200916185747-6507d92df20b3ea50e34effb905bb46f3d94cc3d/lib/github/githooks/push_context.rb:34:in `check'
remote: hooks/pre-receive.rb:52:in `block in <main>'
remote: /data/github/releases/20200916185747-6507d92df20b3ea50e34effb905bb46f3d94cc3d/vendor/gems/2.7.1/ruby/2.7.0/gems/dogstatsd-ruby-4.1.0/lib/datadog/statsd.rb:356:in `time'
remote: hooks/pre-receive.rb:51:in `<main>'
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 45a2d52ef1b728ec2c1124abf968e3d6
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File node_modules/svg-to-img/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-536395/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/Versions/66.0.3347.0/Chromium Framework.framework/Versions/A/Chromium Framework is 119.47 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To github.com:gb221/gradient-twitter.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:gb221/gradient-twitter.git'
```

I've tried clearing all tracked files and re-adding everything ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22924673/6135260)) but that doesn't work.

Comment: delete both .git and .gitignore files and try creating the .gitignore file again while the branch is still untracked

Comment: @Poorna why delete the .git folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the current commit the only (initial) commit in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683279/make-the-current-commit-the-only-initial-commit-in-a-git-repository)

Comment: Given that a repository is a collection of commits, each of which holds a full snapshot of every file, and making a new commit just *adds* to the collection, you can see that the issue here is that you already have a commit that has the file. Adding a new commit that lacks the file is fine, but that old commit still has the file. The duplicate gives a method for making a new history, independent of the history so far; if you then delete the name that finds the *old* history, Git doesn't bother sending it, and eventually the old history fades away entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it by removing all historic commits.

For those also in the same position [I followed this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102849/6135260).