# My .gitignore file not not working although all file is untracked files

Tags: git, gitignore

All files is untracked ,i try add password.txt file to .gitignore but it doesn't work,i already have try other files in untracked list too.

**See Picture:**

[image: screenshot]

Like you see,after add password.txt file to .gitignore ,but in untracked list,it still there!
Someone know how to solve this please !!!!

Comment: Just commit your .gitignore file, Please think to share plain text not image https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: `.gitignore` works even if not committed.

Comment: I still don't know how to solve it bro,why is seem so hard !

Comment: Did you try check the .gitignore encode? See this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924633/gitignore-is-not-ignoring-directories

Comment: I have solved this by convert encoding to utf-8.Tks bro for help.